# Regex match anything after /x/ and before the next /

Tags: regex

`title/x/word/c`

How would I match anything after `/x/` but before the next `/`? (i.e. match `word`)

`\/x\/.+\/` matches `/x/word/` but I'm not sure how to match just `word` it properly (new to regex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a look behind and a negated character class:

```
(?<=/x/)[^/]*
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/ERXc86T0ju).

Look arounds assert without being part of the match.

Comment: Why would they be escaped, `/` isn't a special character in regexes. If you're using JavaScript or something similar and need to escape them, that's your issue, you only tagged your question regex.

Comment: @frosty you would only have to escape the slashes if your app language uses slashes to *delimit* the regex - eg JS or ruby etc - but such slashes are not *part* of the regex, any more than quotes are part of strings in expressions like `"foo"`

Answer (score -1):

`/x/([^/]*)`

This is a simple regular expression. We're matching `/x/` followed by zero or more characters which are not `/`. You just add parentheses where you want to add a *capture group*.